# PostgreSQL: Merge records within a table

Tags: database, postgresql, merge, duplicates

I have one large table which has the following structure:
[image]

As you can see in the image above, the primary key consists of the intervalstart and the edgeid and therefore, there are no duplicate entries within this table.

What I want to do now is to update some edgeids as some of them are deprecated.
For example, I want to update ALL records which have the edgeid "E304178540From" with the new edgeid "E304178582From". As you can see in the image above, this will fail because I would have created a duplicate (but with different values for avgvelocity, measurementcount and vehiclecount).

So as a solution, I want to "merge" those records (in this example the first two entries in the image above) and calculate new values for the avgvelocity, measurementcount and vehiclecount (by calculating the average).

So that it looks like this:

> intervalstart | day | edgeid | avgvelocity | measurementcount | vehiclecount
>
> 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | E304178582From | 85 | 1 | 120

Any suggestions on how to solve this?
Thank you for any help you can give me!

Comment: Please remove mysql tag from this question if your usecase is limited to postgresql database.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use ON Conflcit clause of insert command.  The syntax is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_list) VALUES(value_list)
ON CONFLICT target action;
```

So, Try inserting a new record which will lead to a conflict (based on the timestamp and edgeid), calculate the new avg etc in the on conflict clause.  You can refer to the original values using EXCLUDED pseudo table.

Please refer to the documentation here for more information:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html